# div got z-index clickable while other cant click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two `div`s which are `#top` and `#bottom`. `#top` `div` has `z-index` on the CSS and the `position` is `fixed`, the reason I put `z-index` is to make `#bottom` `div` when scrolling it will make `#top` `div` always on top position and `fixed position`. Both `div` have a button, the only problem is that the button on `#top div` is working. I try to put `pointer-event:none` on `#top div`, `#bottom` can click but `#top` can't click anymore. Is it possible to click the link on both `div` without JavaScript?

This is my [example](https://jsfiddle.net/bobolat/dh5fg8km/7/) which on top can't click. I want both `div` to be clickable.

Comment: Could you create a reduced test case somewhere or provide the minimum amount of code here to reproduce? Hard to say without seeing what's going on.

Comment: @graygilmore edit the question. added link leading to example. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

In this new situation `z-index` is needed.

- Assign the anchor inside the `div#top` an id or class (I assigned it `#link1`).
- Give that new id or class the following styles:

  ```
  #link1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1001;
    pointer-events: auto;
  }
  ```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/wukwro2y/2/)

**Snippet**

```css
#top {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}
#link1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1001;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
  <a id="link1" href="javascript:alert('click too')">ClickAble</a> 
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li><a href="javascript:alert('click too')">ClickAble</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript:alert('click too')">ClickAble</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript:alert('click too')">ClickAble</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript:alert('click too')">ClickAble</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript:alert('click too')">ClickAble</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript:alert('click too')">ClickAble</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript:alert('click too')">ClickAble</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In this situation, you don't really need `z-index`.

- Remove the `div#top`
- Assign the last link the id `#top`
- Change `pointer-events` to `auto` on the `#top` style.

  `<a id="top" href="javascript:alert('click too')">ClickAble</a>`

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/e57xm2ak/2/)

**Snippet**

```css
#bottom {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}
#top {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
  margin-top: 30px;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="bottom">

  <a href="javascript:alert('Finished!')">SubM</a>
  <a href="javascript:alert('click 30px to the left, below the red square')">IT</a>
  <a id="top" href="javascript:alert('click too')">ClickAble</a> 
   
</div>
```

Comment: sorry i update my cases. the example like this actually https://jsfiddle.net/bobolat/dh5fg8km/7/